# How completely disable ENB hotkeys?

Tags: mods, the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

[ENB](http://enbdev.com/index_en.html) has some extreme functionality (for basic usage) tied to [hotkeys](https://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/3839825-enb-hotkeys-and-you/), such as "purging" VRAM by pressing <kbd>F4</kbd>. Some other functions such as the fps-limiter conflict with the keybinds in a game (can't be easily rebinded) and I would prefer disabling the hotkeys entirely as my ENB build is rather minimalistic (only SSAO and SMAA) and doesn't require any configuration.

[On /r/skyrimmods](https://www.reddit.com/r/skyrimmods/comments/585ll8/can_i_completely_disable_some_enb_hotkeys/) it's said that the hotkeys can be turned off by adding `KeyBruteForce=0` to `enblocal.ini`, but the file doesn't exist on my system, only `enbseries.ini` does (**the same method doesn't work**).

Comment: Is this question about Skyrim?  If so, you should tag it as such.

Comment: @MBraedley: No, I tried to ask a general question. The ENB I'm using is for Oblivion.

Comment: @Tyler Shellberg Can you summarize your [deleted] answer in the comments?

Comment: You still should be asking about a specific game.  Using a tag like "mods" should always be accompanied by a game or series specific tag.

Comment: @MBraedley: I've updated now as the ENB seems to differ a lot between Skyrim and the other versions.

Comment: The ENB version for Oblivion and Fallout 3 is a lot older than the one for Skyrim, so the option your looking for may indeed not exist. Did you do a system-wide file search for `enblocal.ini`?

Comment: @Kaizerwolf: Sure, with [Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/).

Comment: Oblivion ENB's don't have an enblocal.ini.

Comment: Just adding here that ENBoost (ENB, but only performance tweaks) for Oblivion does have an enblocal.ini. [user598527's current answer](/a/358133/4797) also applies to ENBoost's enblocal.ini.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `enbseries.ini`, under `[INPUT]`, replace the value of all commands you want to disable with `0`. For instance:

```
KeyFPSLimit=0
KeyShowFPS=0
KeyScreenshot=0
```